# How to use javascript variable with toggle remove code?

Tags: javascript

I have `button` which it false/true for other html select element.

When Button is pressed I want select element is filled with some values - so I have used this code for this purpose:

```
if ($('#make_a_choose').css("display") !== 'none') {

    var select = document.getElementById("myselect_id");
    var options = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];

        for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
            var opt = options[i];
            var el = document.createElement("option");
            el.textContent = opt;
            el.value = opt;
            select.appendChild(el);
        }

}
```

However, when I toggle button and choose true  again I have double (triple...) of them because it simple add values even if they are already presented.

So I decided to remove elements when make_a_choose button turn off again (as false state). I have such code for it:

```
if ($('#make_a_choose').css("display") === 'none') {

  var selectobject=document.getElementById("myselect_id");
  var slenght = selectobject.length;

  for (var i=1; i<slenght; i++){
     selectobject.remove(i);
  }

}
```

The problem that  this code doesn't remove all the select fields,  some of them is not removed. I suppose it  could be because `var slenght = selectobject.length` is changing dynamically while loop is processing. I use i=1 as initial value because I don't want default select value is removed, however if I use i=0 this issue still persist.

Can someone advice how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this please!

```
$("#myselect_id").find('option').not(':first').remove();
```

Instead of:

```
  for (var i=1; i<slenght; i++){
     selectobject.remove(i);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried it but looks like it remove just sole option. Not working for me :(

Comment: Post the code with the HTML and I could help you. ;)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/utkyv4jw/   just press few times the button and you could see an effect. :)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gwt2om59/ here it is the solution, I hope to help you.

Comment: Great! It works! Thank you very much. Appreciate your support!